# How to draw route from source to destination in google map api 3

Tags: asp.net, google-maps-api-3

Below link is very helpful. I want to do extra but I can't. I want to draw route between 2 or more places like google does, in that source code it has only 2 places (Under 'Direction' Section).
Please help me and thanks in advance

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/291499/Google-Maps-API-V3-for-ASP-NET

Comment: But I got solution. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

Google Maps JavaScript API V3 allow map objects to store state and update their presentation automatically by implementing MVC objects.

Two of these may interest you in your project.
[**DirectionsService**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsService) and [**DirectionsWaypoint**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsWaypoint).

Specifically you can use [**Waypoints**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#Waypoints) to provide locations on the route. These waypoints can be made movable.